# How can i get the xml response ( CXFRs webservice)?

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, apache-camel, cxfrs

I get the id from the uri and i put it as a condiontion in my sql request
After i put the result into XML format

This is the function:

```
package com.mycompany.camel.blueprint;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
public class Testws {
    @GET
    @Path("/test/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Integer getAssets(@PathParam("id") int id){

        return id;
    }
  }
```

This is the route:

```
<camelContext id="camel"    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
     <route>
       <from uri="cxfrs://bean://rsServer"/>
       <log message="${body}"/>
       <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.Integer"/>
       <to uri="sql:select * from customers where id=:#${body}?exchangePattern=InOut&amp;dataSource=moodleDB"/>
            </route>    </camelContext>
```

The error after: http://localhost:5070/route/test/1

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

how can i get the xml document? Thanks ?

Comment: What version of apache-camel are you using? Are you sure this error is not as a result of the browser trying to interpret the response as XML and is an invalid XML?

Comment: I'm using Jboss Fuse ESB

Answer (score 0):

To return xml from a camel route using cxfrs you will need a few things:

- A customer object annotated with @XmlRootElement on the class and other xml annotations to tell jaxb how to marshal it
- A xml provider defined in the cxf server like so:

  ```
  <cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="${url}">
      <cxf:serviceBeans>
          <bean class="com.mycompany.camel.blueprint.Testws"/>
      </cxf:serviceBeans>
      <cxf:providers>
          <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.xml.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider"/>
      </cxf:providers>
  </cxf:rsServer>
  ```

You'll need to process the response from the SQL call into a list of customer objects which then cxf can marshal into xml using this provider.

You will need a dependency on jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider to use this.